# My WPF/EntityFramework application don't work on other computer

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have created a WPF application that uses Entity Framework/code first on LocalDb (I have created my database on a "model" directory and all seems fine).

It works pretty good on my laptop and I wanted to share it with my friend but it doesn't work. I think I have a SQL error on the other computer but it doesn't show it. It just shows a windows application error... I think it's when I try to load my database context.

My database context:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ModernUINavigationApp1.Model
{
    class Supcontext : DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<InfosConnexion> InfosConnexions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InfosFichiers> InfosFiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT:**

The localDb is installed, I can build and run a new entity framework solution on every computers and see the localdb on server explorer (on visual studio) for each. On my solution (the one that I try to share) an on an other computer, I have delete the app.config, delete and re-import entity framework, and enable migration and update db on the console and then it works, but it's not the right/better solution I think.

Comment: First the usual suspect: is localDb installed?

Comment: There's not enough for us to go on here. What is the connection string to your “model” directory? How are you storing and retrieving it? How are you installing your app on the other computer? What does “dont work” mean? Does it show an error? Tell us the error message. Why do you think you “have an sql error on an other computer”?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! For example if i copy my VS2013 solution to an other computer, i can't start my application on visual studio. I can build it but it don't run. My application start with a call to my Dbcontext and it just freeze the application.

Comment: My database is local, i use no connection string, i just build and run my application on my computer and it works but if i move my solution on an other computer it don't works anymore. I have find the reason i think its cause my db is not generate on an other computer.

Comment: Yeah, well, I asked you a question.

Comment: Yes sorry, the localDb is installed, i can build and run a new entity framework solution on this computers and see the localdb on server explorer (on visual studio). On my solution (the one that i try to share) an on an other computer, I have delete the app.config, delete and re-import entity framework, and enable migration and update db on the console and then it works, but its not the right/better solution i think.

Comment: LocalDB requires a connection string; if you don't have one then it will never work. However, since you say it works on your local machine I suspect you have a connection string like `Data Source=C:\Users\Nimp\visual studio\my project\test.mdf`, which only exists on your machine.

Comment: No i dont have this string in my solution and it works without (i have search on all my solution i have no "Data Source" occurence).

Comment: Your solution does not make sense. You should never change source code to make it work on another computer. It should work without changes.

Comment: oh ok i understand, but i dont know how to make it different, cause its  generated line made by entity framework, and the localdb reference seems to be different on each computer (if its the right problem).

Comment: Ah voila. what are the exact lines that differ?

Comment: I'm sorry i cant check it for the moment, it was for a school group project and i'm no more with my teammates for check/see. When i can check it i will answer, i let the "solution" and edit with "temporary" for the moment cause remove and install entity framework again on the solution works, but i think you right its not the best solution, maybe edit just one or two lines on the original solution would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you open an already existing Visual Studio solution with entity framework (and localdb) from an other computer, you have to delete entity framework from this solution by:

1. right clicking on the solution (on the solution explorer in visual studio),
2. choosing packet manager
3. removing entity framework and install it again (also in the packet manager).

This will generate a new `app.config` with the correct lines configuration and it should work.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30824417/4) to the question [My WPF/EntityFramework application don't work on other computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824417/my-wpf-entityframework-application-dont-work-on-other-computer) by the OP [Nimp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4500451/nimp) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>