# System.StackOverflowException error while converting visual studio 2013 project to 2015 using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, ef-code-first

We have created "MVC Project in Visual studio 2012 Ultimate" and have used "Code First". Now We want to convert this project into "Visual studio 2015 Professional".

Current Project Configuration :--

.Net Framework Version : 4.5

MVC Version :  5.0 (5.2.2)

Used Entity Framework: 6.0 (6.1.1)

Issue: We have got the error in "OnModelCreating" function. Below I have written snippet code.

```
protected virtual void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) <---       Error throw at this line System.StackOverflowException
{
   //Foreign key relation

}
```

[image: StackOVerFlow Exception error may be due to recursion]

Different different issue which we have faced

1.Sometime when I comment Foreign key relation in OnModelCreating method than it's work fine. 
2.Possible reason for this error may be recursion but it was earlier working fine in VS 2012 and VS 2013. Now what's wrong with this Visual studio 2015 version.
3.In Visual studio 2015 some portion of OnModelCreating method works fine in one machine but the same code does not work in other machine.

Comment: @GertArnold I am already  using Entity Framework 6.1.3 in my project from starting but this is not a issue at all. May be some dependacy on Entity Framework 6.1.3 could be but I have not find anything any where.

Comment: @GertArnold Actually I have tried both first 6.1.1 and than 6.1.3 version of EF.

Comment: So the "Current Project Configuration" applies to the VS2012 project as well? I thought .Net 4.5 wasn't supported in VS2012 (don't remember). Just for sure: did you (re)install the EF NuGet package in VS2015?

Comment: @GertArnold Yes I have reinstalled EF from Nuget package so I have latest version 6.1.3 which I am using and .Net 4.5 was supported in VS2012 as we have already worked on that.

Comment: Have you try to delete every directory containing compiled objects? Because the error is thrown in a very strange position. It seems that you have some debug informations not aligned with the code. Also, are you sure that you are compiling everything for every platform (see build configurations for this)?

Comment: Hi ! @bubi Actually could not understand your query that "Have you try to delete every directory containing compiled objects?" by this point what you are suggesting to me? Even I could not understand by " Also, are you sure that you are compiling everything for every platform (see build configurations for this)?". Can you please elaborate in detail ?

Comment: I mean, the exception is raised in a quite strange position so I think that your executables (dlls in your case) and source code could be not aligned. In this case Visual Studio shows a wrong line as the line that raised the exception. Sometimes, right clicking on the project and clicking clean is not enough; in this case I exit from the project, I delete everything other than source code and I recompile it

Comment: @bubi yes you are write that this exception shows wrong line. Sometimes when I clean and rebuild the project than it works fine but next time when I run the project without any changes it gives me same error. This is really unpreictable behaviour ever I have seen of Visual Studio. I have tried almost evetything but finally I thought this  might be Visual studio 2015's issue.

Comment: Have you tried to reintegrate EF to the solution like described in http://stackoverflow.com/q/30824417/3090544

Comment: @MarkusEgle Still I haven't try as described in your given link. Let me try it later. It might can solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have resolved Sytem.StackOverflowException error by creating separate class for Fluent API as it's memory exception issue and by dividing Fluent API file into multiple file(Unexpected solutions but it's working fine), I have resolved it. May be this issue occured due to large numbers of lines coding(more than 10000 lines of coding earlier I have) in Fluent API so it's behaviour is different for different machines(computers) with different configurations and based on CPU usages.

For Example

If u have earlier ModelCreating file as below

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{        
    modelBuilder.HasMany(e => e.LoginC)
    .WithOptional(e => e.LoginLoginC)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Cmp_Id, e.Login_C_Id });       


     modelBuilder.HasMany(e => e.LoginU)
    .WithOptional(e => e.LoginLoginU)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Cmp_Id, e.Login_U_Id});   


     modelBuilder.HasMany(e => e.LoginD)
     .WithOptional(e => e.LoginLoginD)
     .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Cmp_Id, e.Login_D_Id });

}
```

Now Separate LoginEntity to overcome this issue as given below

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{                 

     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LoginEntityTypeConfiguration());

}
```

Now Create Separate class file named as LoginEntityTypeConfiguration.cs

```
public class LoginEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Login>
{
    public LoginEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(e => e.LoginC)
        .WithOptional(e => e.LoginLoginC)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Cmp_Id, e.Login_C_Id });            

        this.HasMany(e => e.LoginU)
        .WithOptional(e => e.LoginLoginU)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Cmp_Id, e.Login_U_Id });

        this.HasMany(e => e.LoginD)
        .WithOptional(e => e.LoginLoginD)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Cmp_Id, e.Login_D_Id });            

   }
}
```

To Create Separate Class for Fluent API in Entity Framework, you can take reference from http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/move-configurations-to-seperate-class-in-code-first.aspx

Now most probably it could resolve your issue, if your issue is still not resolved than you can devide your LoginEntityTypeConfiguration.cs file into multiple classes as given below

```
// LoginEntityTypeConfiguration.cs
 public class LoginEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Login>
 {
    public LoginEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(e => e.LoginC)
        .WithOptional(e => e.LoginLoginC)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Cmp_Id, e.Login_C_Id });            

       // Create instance of newly created separate file than call it's method
        LoginPart1EntityTypeConfiguration LoginPart1EntityTypeConfiguration = new LoginPart1EntityTypeConfiguration();
        LoginPart1EntityTypeConfiguration.LoginEntityTypeConfiguration(this);            

   }
}

 /// create LoginPart1EntityTypeConfiguration.cs file

public class LoginPart1EntityTypeConfiguration
{
    public void LoginEntityTypeConfiguration(LoginEntityTypeConfiguration LoginEntityTypeConfiguration)
    {

         LoginEntityTypeConfiguration.HasMany(e => e.LoginU)
        .WithOptional(e => e.LoginLoginU)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Cmp_Id, e.Login_U_Id });


        LoginEntityTypeConfiguration.HasMany(e => e.LoginD)
        .WithOptional(e => e.LoginLoginD)
        .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Cmp_Id, e.Login_D_Id });

 }

}
```

I hope this could help you to over come from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What I would probably do is start commenting out a bunch of Entities from the DbSet/Model and keep doing that until it worked once.  Then I would slowly re-add them to see which model is causing the issue.  If you comment out all the DbSets/Models and it still crashes, then you need to push Ctrl-Alt-E and check the 2nd box so you break on ALL exceptions to see if you can find a deeper exception.  Otherwise, we need to see the exact line of code that is dying or we probably won't be able to help much.